# Python PIL: color index to RGB

Tags: python, image

following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python-programaticly) i was able to load and read pixels from a .gif. That question specifically askes for a RGB value, but the accepted (and most voted answer) that I used as reference gets me to get an int as value. What is it? I guess some sort of index, but how to convert it to a proper rgb value? Thanks

```
[..]
img = Image.open(GIF_FILENAME)
pix = img.load()
for i in range(5):
    print img.getpixel((i, 0))
    # this returns me like 78, 65.. how to get RGB?
[..]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
img = Image.open(GIF_FILENAME)
rgbimg = img.convert('RGB')
for i in range(5):
    print rgbimg.getpixel((i, 0))
```