# Help editing a picture in python

Tags: python, image-processing

I have to suppose I'm given a picture, there shouldnt be any user inputs or calls to media.chose file, so given a picture return the average red value of all the Pixels in that Picture (as an int). If the average calculation results in a non-integer value, then truncate the result. For example, if you average the values 10, 6 and 4, the result would be 6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read the RGB value of a given pixel in Python, Programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python-programatically)

Answer (score 1):

The question is almost answered here

- [How can I read the RGB value of a given pixel in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python-programaticly)

Use PIL to load the image, read it pixel by pixel and do your calculation.

Comment: Close as duplicate rather than duplicating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/)