# Pixel by pixel data in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pixel

I want to do the following:

- Load a png image to the Python code
- Get the pixel by pixel RGB data in three arrays, one each for R, G and B. I mean R[i,j] should give me the value of R at the i,j th pixel of the image.
- Once I have the arrays I can always edit data.
- Plot the edited data using the three array R,G and B and save it as another png image

How to do it in python?

Comment: See answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python-programatically

Comment: @lovespeed. Since you already know the high level of what you want to do, you're half-way there. The other half is trying to do the individual steps. Why not go learn how to load an image in python, and post a question only *after* you get stuck doing that.

Answer (score 8):

use PIL to load the image:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('yourimage.png')
```

I'm going to suggest a method that messes directly with the image data, without accessing individual pixels by coordinates.

You can get the image data in one big byte string:

```
data = img.tostring()
```

You should check `img.mode` for the pixel format.
Assuming it's 'RGBA', the following code will give you separate channels:

```
R = data[::4]
G = data[1::4]
B = data[2::4]
A = data[3::4]
```

If you want to access pixels by coordinate you could do something like:

```
width = img.size[0]
pixel = (R[x+y*width],G[x+y*width],B[x+y*width],A[x+y*width])
```

Now to put it back together, there's probably a better way, but you can use `zip`:

```
new_data = zip(R,G,B,A)
```

And reuce:

```
new_data = ''.join(reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, zip(R,G,B,A)))
```

Then to save the picture:

```
new_img = Image.fromstring('RGBA', img.size, new_data)
new_img.save('output.png')
```

And here's everything together in an example that zeros the red channel:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('yourimage.png')

data = img.tostring()
R = data[::4]
G = data[1::4]
B = data[2::4]
A = data[3::4]

R = '\0' * len(R)

new_data = ''.join(reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, zip(R,G,B,A)))
new_img = Image.fromstring('RGBA', img.size, new_data)
new_img.save('output.png')
```

Comment: `tostring()` is deprecated, instead use `data = str(img.tobytes)`