# what exactly is the tkinter getRGB() image argument supposed to be? (python)

Tags: python, image-processing, tkinter, filepath

I'm making a program to print out the color values of pixels in an image and referencing [chenlian's answer to a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/how-can-i-read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python) to read RGB values. I isolated this part of the program into a different file to test it.

`pic = "H://fourpxtest.png"
from tkinter import *
def getRGB(image, x, y):
    value = image.get(x, y)
    return tuple(map(int, value.split(" ")))
getRGB(pic, 1, 1)`

is all i have right now. running this returns

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/tzrtst.py", line 6, in <module>
    getRGB(pic, 1, 1)
  File "H:/tzrtst.py", line 4, in getRGB
    value = image.get(x, y)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`

What is `image` supposed to be exactly? I've tried replacing the words `image` with my `pic` variable in both spots and `pic` with `image` but it makes no difference. Can image be a filepath like what I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

image has to be an instance of PhotoImage, not the file name http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
else:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

grape_gif='''\
R0lGODlhIAAgALMAAAAAAAAAgHCAkC6LV76+vvXeswD/ANzc3DLNMubm+v/6zS9PT6Ai8P8A////
/////yH5BAEAAAkALAAAAAAgACAAAAS00MlJq7046803AF3ofAYYfh8GIEvpoUZcmtOKAO5rLMva
0rYVKqX5IEq3XDAZo1GGiOhw5rtJc09cVGo7orYwYtYo3d4+DBxJWuSCAQ30+vNTGcxnOIARj3eT
YhJDQ3woDGl7foNiKBV7aYeEkHEignKFkk4ciYaImJqbkZ+PjZUjaJOElKanqJyRrJyZgSKkokOs
NYa2q7mcirC5I5FofsK6hcHHgsSgx4a9yzXK0rrV19gRADs=
'''

def getRGB(image, x, y):
    value = image.get(x, y)
    return value


master=tk.Tk()
master.geometry("300x500")

## uses data= instead of file= because the picture
## is data within this program
photo=tk.PhotoImage(data=grape_gif)
print getRGB(photo, 10, 10)
```

Comment: It runs fine, but every time i run it, it tells me the values are all 255 regardless of my specified pixel

Comment: Is there a lot of white in the picture?

Comment: the picture is 4 pixels, one completely red, one completely green, one completely blue, and one completely white in a square shape

Comment: It is impossible to tell what is happening until you post the new code that you are using, but your original question has been answered, the argument sent to the function is a PhotoImage instance, not a string, so you should start a new thread with a new question and the new code.