# Iterating through all pixels, if within range, change pixel to black, else to white

Tags: python, opencv, pixel, mask

So basically, i want to iterate over all my pixels, and if they are withing range, change their RGB values to white, else to black.

I've seen a couple of examples where a mask is used, but i'm a ittle confused as to how i would use a mask to compare an RGB value.
My range is as such

```
min_YCrCb = np.array([0,133,77],np.uint8) 
max_YCrCb = np.array([255,173,127],np.uint8)
```

So first i have my image,img, in YCrCb. How do i create a mask such that it'll see if the RGB is in range, and once that's done, how do i set them to black and white?

Comment: black is 0,0,0.  White is 255,255,255.  You don't need to check R since it's range is the whole thing.  Check G and B with the two extremes you want

Comment: But how do i check G and B? I can't figure out how to access the RGB of a pixel in general

Comment: Not sure about 'mask' but 132 < G < 174, and similar for B

Comment: Look here maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/how-can-i-read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to use a mask. Comparing the rgb values of pixels using for loops takes too long

Comment: cv::inRange creates a mask for some range

Answer (score 2):

I think the [inRange](http://opencv.itseez.com/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=inrange#cv2.inRange) method is what you need.

So, in your example you could use:

```
# Keep in mind that OpenCV stores things in BGR order, not RGB
lowerBound = cv.Scalar(0, 133, 770)
upperBound = cv.Scalar(255, 173, 127)

# this gives you the mask for those in the ranges you specified
cv.InRange(cv_input, lowerBound, upperBound, cv_output);
```

For each pixel in your cv_input, if its value is in the given range, it will be set to 255 (all 1s), otherwise 0. If you want the inverse, you can use `Not` method.

```
# This will set all bits in cv_input 
cv.Not(cv_output, cv_inverse)
```