# Get Pixel count using RGB values in Python

Tags: python

I have to find count of pixels of RGB which is using by RGB values. So i need logic for that one.

Example.

i have image called image.jpg. That image contains width = 100 and height = 100 and Red value is 128. Green is 0 and blue is 128. so that i need to find how much RGB pixels have that image. can anyone help?

Comment: Have you looked at the `pillow` library?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/how-can-i-read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python

Comment: Do you mean you want to find out how many pixels have a certain colour? Or how many pixels there are in the image in total (which would be width*height)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/how-can-i-read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python) question, by using `Pillow` you can do the following:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('image.jpg', 'r')
```

If successful, this function returns an Image object. You can now use instance attributes to examine the file contents:

```
width, height = im.size
pixel_values = list(im.getdata()) 
print(im.format, im.size, im.mode)
```

The `format` attribute identifies the source of an image. If the image was not read from a file, it is set to None. The `mode` attribute defines the number and names of the bands in the image, and also the pixel type and depth. Common modes are “L” (luminance) for greyscale images, “RGB” for true color images, and “CMYK” for pre-press images.