# Image to and from array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

When I import an image as a NumPy array using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
imgage = Image.open('input.jpg', 'r')
width, height = imgage.size
pixel_values = np.array(imgage.getdata(), dtype=np.uint8).reshape((width, height, 3))
```

And, then I export it using the following code:

```
output = Image.fromarray(pixel_values, 'RGB')
output = img.save('output.png')
```

The resulting image is completely different from the input.

Can you please what the problem is? How can I fix it?

Comment: I used the reshape function according to [How to read the RGB value of a given pixel in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/how-to-read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python), however, it seems that the correct usage is `reshape((height, width, 3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but when you reshape your image, you need to invert `width` and `height`.

```
pixel_values = np.array(imgage.getdata(), dtype=np.uint8).reshape((height, width, 3))
```

Also, on a different note, if you want to convert a PIL Image to a numpy array you just have to do

```
pixel_values = np.array(imgage)
```