# Wrong pixel color with Python?

Tags: python, macos, applescript

I'm trying to get the pixel color from the screen at the coordinates x = 386, y = 1131 from the top left hand corner of the screen.

When I run

```py
import PIL.ImageGrab
from time import sleep
sleep(2)
rgb2 = PIL.ImageGrab.grab().load()[386,1131]
couleur = list(rgb2)
del couleur[3]
couleur = '#%02x%02x%02x' % tuple(couleur)
print(couleur)
```

in python it gives me `#2f3136` which is definitely a wrong color.

It should be `#fb8908` like this script in AppleScript gives me :

```
delay 2
set colour to ""
set colour to do shell script "screencapture -R386,1131,1,1 -t bmp $TMPDIR/test.bmp && 
              xxd -p -l 3 -s 54 $TMPDIR/test.bmp | 
                   sed 's/\\(..\\)\\(..\\)\\(..\\)/\\3\\2\\1/'"
display dialog colour
```

I also tried to invert the x and y in the Python version but it still gives me another color than orange.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try `print('#%02x%02x%02x' % PIL.ImageGrab.grab((x,y,x+1,y+1)).getpixel((0,0)))` where `x, y = 386, 1131`.

Comment: I just ran 
`import PIL.ImageGrab
from time import sleep
sleep(2)
x = 386
y = 1131
print('#%02x%02x%02x' % PIL.ImageGrab.grab((x,y,x+1,y+1)).getpixel((0,0)))`

But the terminal returned : `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: Try grabbing 50-100 pixels around your expected area and saving them as a file to see if you are looking in the correct area.

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: I think the returned image is in `RGBA` mode, so use `print('#%02x%02x%02x' % ImageGrab.grab((x,y,x+1,y+1)).getpixel((0,0))[:3])`.

Comment: There is no error while running but it still gives #2f3136.

Comment: You better take a screen shot of the whole screen and inspect the pixel color using image editor program.

Comment: Instead of the full screen, I tried
`from subprocess import call
from time import sleep
sleep(2)
call(["screencapture", "-R386,1131,1,1", "screenshot.jpg"])`
and it gets the right pixel to extract the color from. Now I just need to get its color.

Answer (score 0):

After some tries, I finally got a solution.
I got inspired with the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/how-to-read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python) and searched a solution to get a screenshot from the screen.
I don't know why AppleScript and Python give different hex code but the most important thing is that Python returns an orange color.

Here is the code

```html
from PIL import Image
from time import sleep
from subprocess import call
sleep(2)
call(["screencapture", "-R386,1131,1,1", "screenshot.jpg"])
im = Image.open('/Users/kevinshao/screenshot.jpg')
pix = im.load()
print('#%02x%02x%02x' % pix[1,1][:3])
```

Thanks @MarkSetchell and @acw1668 for helping me.

Comment: Why `pix[1,1]` is used but not `pix[0,0]`?

Comment: Because I don't think an image have a pixel with [0,0] as coordinates.

Comment: They are indexes.  Python index starts from zero.  I wonder `pix[0,0]` gives the same result from `ImageGrab.grab()`.