# Marking a point in the image with given RGBA values using PIL, matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I am working with Image Processing and python. I have an array of RGBA values for 10 different points in the image and one of the points is given below.

I have the following RGBA value of a given pixel in the image:

```
[42,25,16,255]
```

I want to mark this particular pixel with a 'dot' in the same image. I have tried this ([How to read the RGB value of a given pixel in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/how-to-read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python)) but I could not get it to work.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to proceed further.

Any help might be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what your intention is? Do you have one particular pixel that you want to give another color? Do you want to draw a circle on top of each pixel with exactly that color?

Comment: I want to draw a circle over the given pixel. So basically mark that point (pixel) with a star/circle/cross to visualize that pixel on the image.

Comment: In that case, you want to create a method that draws a circle at a given center, loop over all pixel data, and if the pixel color is identical to [42,25,16,255], you invoke the aforementioned method for that pixel as center of the circle.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.