# Using the pygame function pygame.pixelcopy.surface_to_array()

Tags: python, pygame

I've been sitting on this for a while now but the documentation is really confusing and has no examples.

I'm trying to store the rgb values of every pixel in a surface. I've tried the following code:

```
original_pixels = numpy.zeros((wn_width, wn_height, 3))
pygame.pixelcopy.surface_to_array(original_pixels, wn, 'P')
```

but it throws the error `ValueError: Unsupport array item type`.

From the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelcopy.html):

> surface_to_array(array, surface, kind='P', opaque=255, clear=0) ->
> None The surface_to_array function copies pixels from a Surface object
> to a 2D or 3D array. Depending on argument kind and the target array
> dimension, a copy may be raw pixel value, RGB, a color component
> slice, or colorkey alpha transparency value. Recognized kind values
> are the single character codes 'P', 'R', 'G', 'B', 'A', and 'C'. Kind
> codes are case insensitive, so 'p' is equivalent to 'P'. The first two
> dimensions of the target must be the surface size (w, h).
>
> The default 'P' kind code does a direct raw integer pixel (mapped)
> value copy to a 2D array and a 'RGB' pixel component (unmapped) copy
> to a 3D array having shape (w, h, 3). For an 8 bit colormap surface
> this means the table index is copied to a 2D array, not the table
> value itself. A 2D array's item size must be at least as large as the
> surface's pixel byte size. The item size of a 3D array must be at
> least one byte.
>
> For the 'R', 'G', 'B', and 'A' copy kinds a single color component of
> the unmapped surface pixels are copied to the target 2D array. For
> kind 'A' and surfaces with source alpha (the surface was created with
> the SRCALPHA flag), has a colorkey (set with Surface.set_colorkey()),
> or has a blanket alpha (set with Surface.set_alpha()) then the alpha
> values are those expected for a SDL surface. If a surface has no
> explicit alpha value, then the target array is filled with the value
> of the optional opaque surface_to_array argument (default 255: not
> transparent).
>
> Copy kind 'C' is a special case for alpha copy of a source surface
> with colorkey. Unlike the 'A' color component copy, the clear argument
> value is used for colorkey matches, opaque otherwise. By default, a
> match has alpha 0 (totally transparent), while everything else is
> alpha 255 (totally opaque). It is a more general implementation of
> pygame.surfarray.array_colorkey()Copy the colorkey values into a 2d
> array.
>
> Specific to surface_to_array, a ValueError is raised for target arrays
> with incorrect shape or item size. A TypeError is raised for an
> incorrect kind code. Surface specific problems, such as locking, raise
> a pygame.error.

By the way if you can just recommend a different approach to achieve the same goal it's all good.

Comment: Using Pillow <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/how-to-read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, but by default [`numpy.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) creates an array of *floats*. However, for use with [`pygame.pixelcopy.surface_to_array`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelcopy.html#pygame.pixelcopy.surface_to_array) the datatype must be *uint8*:

```py
original_pixels = numpy.zeros((wn_width, wn_height, 3), dtype=numpy.uint8)
pygame.pixelcopy.surface_to_array(original_pixels, wn, 'P')
```