# Get color of specific pixel in image using python

Tags: python

is it possible to get color of specific pixel from image using python?
Something like:
`colorOfPixel = pixel(1, 9)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read the RGB value of a given pixel in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/how-to-read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at another answer I found, [on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/how-to-read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python), it appears as though 'It's probably best to use the Python Image Library to do this which I'm afraid is a separate download.'

It's quite a good answer, I'd recommend checking it out!