# Is there a spec for RGB values of the emoji skin tone modifiers?

Tags: unicode, colors

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols_and_Pictographs#Emoji_modifiers) and [Unicode.org](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-modifiers.html) both illustrate the emoji skin tone modifiers.

Where are the RGB values specified? (Surely this can't be the font designer's arbitrary choice... there must be a reference somewhere that shows it.)

Comment: Do you know that the Q is supposed to be off-topic here?

Answer (score 0):

Read [Emoji Modifier Sequence](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-modifier-sequence/) at https://emojipedia.org/:

> Emoji characters can be modified to use one of five different skin
> tone modifiers. Each tone is based on the [Fitzpatrick Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitzpatrick_scale).

The [Fitzpatrick Skin Type Classification system](https://www.skininc.com/science/physiology/article/21882228/the-fitzpatrick-skin-type-classification-scale) was developed in 1975 by Harvard Medical School dermatologist Thomas Fitzpatrick, MD, PhD. This system classifies complexions and their tolerance of sunlight…

Read the [Fitzpatrick skin phototype](https://www.arpansa.gov.au/sites/default/files/legacy/pubs/RadiationProtection/FitzpatrickSkinType.pdf?acsf_files_redirect) document as well…

### Edit

[Fitzpatrick Scale / Von Luschan’s Chromatic Scale](https://opencriticalcare.org/faq/how-is-skin-color-measured-for-the-purposes-of-oximeter-performance-validation/)

> The Von  Luschan’s Scale was developed as a tool to assess racial
> classifications according to skin color. It consists of 36 colored
> tiles which are compared to a person’s skin color.
>
> This image is a reproduction of the Von Luschan scale which was
> originally created by Felix von Luschan and printed in Voelker,
> Rassen, Sprachen (1927). The original chart was scanned and the skin
> colors were copied using the paint program’s dropper tool.
>
> Our team at Open Oximetry calculated the RBG values which are
> superimposed on the image of the scale. Notably, 13 and 14 were found
> to have the same RGB values.
> [image]

**Note 1**: get your own values:

Take any image of [von Luschan scale](https://www.google.com/search?q=von%20Luschan%20scale&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjEroHXkqL9AhXKkv0HHaZxB6kQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=von%20Luschan%20scale&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIFCAAQgAQyBggAEAgQHjIHCAAQgAQQGDIHCAAQgAQQGFDxEFjxEGCaFWgAcAB4AIABZ4gBwgGSAQMxLjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=JmHyY8SDCcql9u8PpuOdyAo&bih=710&biw=1024) (or Fitzpatrick one), open it in an image editor (e.g. as simple as Windows' native `mspaint.exe`), use the *Colour Picker* tool to get the RGB values:

[image]

or get them programmatically: [How to read the RGB value of a given pixel in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/)…

**Note 2**: Caution! There are different ways of converting the 36 categories of the *von Luschan scale* to the six categories of the *Fitzpatrick scale* (example in PowerShell):

```
$Fitzpatrick = @'
Type;Effect of Light Exposure;Description;Von Luschan’s Description;Von Luschan’s Color
I;Always burns, never tans;Pale, fair, freckles;Very light;1-5
II;Usually burns, sometimes tans;Fair;Light;6-10
III;May burn, usually tans;Light brown;Intermediate;11-15
IV;Rarely burns, always tans;Olive brown;Mediterranean;16-21
V;Moderate constitutional pigmentation;Brown;Dark or brown;22-28
VI;Marked constitutional pigmentation;Black;Very dark or black;29-36
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'
$Fitzpatrick | Select-Object -Property (
    "Type","Von Luschan’s Color","Von Luschan’s Description") |
        Out-Default
<#
```

(based on *TABLE V.—Skin Classification by Pigmentation* (page 21) in
[*Imaging skin: Past, present and future perspectives*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/41669565_Imaging_skin_Past_present_and_future_perspectives)
by [*Marty O. Visscher*](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Marty-Visscher))

```
<##>

$FitzpatrickWiki = @'
Type;von Luschan scale;Also called
I;0–6;Very light or white, "Celtic" type[5]
II;7–13;Light or light-skinned European[5]
III;14–20;Light intermediate, or dark-skinned European[5]
IV;21–27;Dark intermediate or "olive skin"[5]
V;28–34;Dark or "brown" type
VI;35–36;Very dark or "black" type
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ";"
$FitzpatrickWiki | Out-Default
<#
```

(based on this Wikipedia table:
*the 36 categories of the von Luschan scale in relation to the six categories of the Fitzpatrick scale* in
[Von Luschan's chromatic scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Luschan%27s_chromatic_scale))

<##>

**Result**: `\SO\75489304.ps1`

> ```
> Type Von Luschan’s Color Von Luschan’s Description
> ---- ------------------- -------------------------
> I    1-5                 Very light
> II   6-10                Light
> III  11-15               Intermediate
> IV   16-21               Mediterranean
> V    22-28               Dark or brown
> VI   29-36               Very dark or black
>
>
>
> Type von Luschan scale Also called
> ---- ----------------- -----------
> I    0–6               Very light or white, "Celtic" type[5]
> II   7–13              Light or light-skinned European[5]
> III  14–20             Light intermediate, or dark-skinned European[5]
> IV   21–27             Dark intermediate or "olive skin"[5]
> V    28–34             Dark or "brown" type
> VI   35–36             Very dark or "black" type
> ```

Comment: Yes, I found a link to the Fitzpatrick scale, but there's no RGB value references.

Comment: @JasonS Answer edited (with loathness).

Comment: OK.... but what I see here is there doesn't look like there's any standard values for font designers to implement the emoji skin tone modifiers. Maybe that's the answer....

Comment: I can get my own values of RGB by opening the images of the two references I gave in the question (Wikipedia and unicode.org) in a paint program and analyzing them myself. But that's not my question, I'm looking for how I know the values are correct according to a specification.

Comment: @JasonS the appearance of emoji is left, by design, to font designers; the specification only defines what the pictograms should aim represent. It isn't even prescribed that "standard" emoji like `` should be yellow, let alone what shade of yellow.

Comment: ugh, that seems bad, how do they know what spec to meet? With regular characters the color matches the color of the font.